# How do I deploy a monolithic Django/React app?

Tags: reactjs, django, deployment, spotify

I’m trying to find a way to deploy my app that uses Django on the backend and React front end, and also uses the Spotify API.

The project is based on [this tutorial by Tech With Tim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lsq9oRZ2WiU&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kCLWnGmK0jUBmGLaJxvi4j&index=16)

I’ve seen some tutorials that suggest splitting it up and deploying them as two apps, where the backend proxies API requests to the backend as necessary, however since my React app is served with Django, I don’t think this method is conducive to how my app is set up. I've tried to deploy with Heroku but I haven't been successful. I'm not sure if its relevant, but I used webpack.

[Here's my folder structure:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDphr.png)

Any help? I’d be much obliged.